# "Can't detect any devices"

Tags: mining-hardware, cgminer, gpu

I'm trying to start mining using my GPU (ATI Radeon HD 4850) but when I try to run cgminer it cant detect any devices.
I use this to run cgminer: cgminer --scrypt -o stratum+tcp://stratum2.dogechain.info:3333 -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD
Im very nooby so if you can help that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Its ok I found out what was the problem- I had to update my drivers

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check

1. cgminer --version  - Is the version 3.7.2? if you are using a more recent version you should downgrade it doesn't support GPU mining.
2. in the install dir run ./config.status --config  You should get at least the following output '--enable-opencl' '--enable-scrypt'  if you have correctly compiled with scrypt dependencies.